# Is it possible to remove oracle ADF component from a web application and make it pure JSF?

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

We have an oracle forms application, and one of the many thoughts (considered converting to non-oracle-form technology) was to use JHeadStart (oracle product) that converts the oracle forms to ADF application. But we would like to not use ADF, so is there any way that we can remove the dependency on ADF?

If anyone feels this is not the question to ask, instead of giving me -ve marks please comment me and I will remove this question.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to use pure JSF (components). You will be missing a lot of rich components. But that depends on what you have used so far. You could consider to start using PrimeFaces or BootsFaces. Probably this question will be closed.

Comment: First of all thanks Jasper for providing feedback/asking. To answer your question best of my knowlwdge : Because JHeadStart converts oracle forms code to ADF, one reason to use pure JSF so that we can avoid ADF business component license fees (not sure how much) and use primeFaces for UI. This question can be marked as answered/ closed.

Answer (score 0):

As always, it depends on what you want to achieve. I don't know JHeadStart, but to me, it sounds like a tool converting a legacy application to a framework that might be considered legacy soon. There are a few supporters of ADF, so I believe it's a good thing if you're ready to live with the compromises a full-stack framework brings. But in general, ADF is not popular among JSF developers (mostly because of those compromises, which often turn out to be too restrictive). Even more generally speaking, JSF is not popular among UI developers. That, in turn, is a bit unfair, but I observe a huge movement to pure JavaScript UI frameworks.

This indicates that using a tool like JHeadStart isn't the most future-proof approach. It's (probably) good to survive the next month, but in the long run, it'll probably backfire.

Let's have a look at the question from another angle. Why do you want to get rid of Oracle forms? Most likely, it's because of recruiting problems, but it might also have something to do with architecture. Oracle Forms supports a programming style integrating the database layer tightly with the UI layer. That's a very efficient way to write small applications, but it scales badly if your application grows.

So I'd recommend spending some extra money and time to re-implement your application from scratch. Automated tools tend to generate code that's hard to maintain. Re-designing your application from scratch gives you the opportunity to build an application that lasts a decade.

Oh, and I don't think it's possible to use JHeadStart without introducing ADF. Simply because JHeadStart has been designed with ADF in mind.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen. Really appreciate your feedback.